# Prime number program generating a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error message in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm just starting with C and with Computer Science in general and my handbook (*Programming in C, 4th edition by Stephen G. Kochan*) uses as an example a program to create a list of prime numbers. I decided to try it myself before checking his implementation and to add an option in which the user can decide up to what number he wants to find the prime numbers. I'm using Code::Blocks with the GCC Compiler.

I am receiving the following error message every time I type the number: Segmentation Fault (core dumped).

I know it means I'm trying to access memory I'm not "allowed" to access, but I cannot figure out what part of my code is producing it. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main (void)

{
    int uNumber, divisor;
    bool isPrime;
    printf("Until what number do you want to check? ");
    scanf("%i", uNumber);

    for (uNumber; uNumber>=2; uNumber--)
        {
            isPrime = true;

            for (divisor=uNumber - 1; divisor >=2; divisor--)
                if (uNumber % divisor == 0)
                    isPrime= false;
                if (isPrime != false)
                    printf("%i", uNumber);
        }
}
```

Comment: you don't have curly-braces for your embedded for-loop, and it's probably not acting as you expect it to there.

Comment: `scanf("%i", uNumber);` ->  `scanf("%i", &uNumber);`

Comment: Your `scanf` is wrong, so `uNumber` never gets defined properly. You want: `scanf("%i",&uNumber);` because you have to pass `scanf` a _pointer_ to `uNumber` If you had compiled with the additional options: `-Wall -O2` [as you should always do], most compilers would flag the `scanf` with a warning.

Comment: @CraigEstey: `-Wall`, yes. But must you optimize to get the warning?

Comment: Depends on the compiler. `clang` usually does a pretty good job without `-O2`, but, some compilers (e.g. `gcc`) need optimization because some of the warning/error detection code is only run with optimization on.  This might also flag the missing curly braces on the inner `for`

Comment: @CraigEstey: I got warnings for both the scanf and the missing braces with `-O0` using gcc 6.4.0 on Cygwin.

Comment: @FredLarson Yup. I didn't try this one specifically myself, but I've had cases where some warnings only occur with `-O`

Comment: The scanf specifier should probably be `%d`  (if you don't know the difference between `%d` and `%i`, then you want `%d`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
scanf("%i", uNumber);
```

The `%i` format specifier expects a pointer to an `int`, i.e. an `int *`.  Because parameters in C are pass by value, it needs a pointer so that it can write to the variable in the calling function.

What you're passing in instead is an `int`.  The current value of this variable is then treated as a valid pointer value (which is most likely isn't) which causes the program to crash.

Use the address-of operator `&` to pass the address of `uNumber`:

```
scanf("%i", &uNumber);
```